# Highcharts: stacked bar charts tooltip enable shared and keep display arrow

Tags: highcharts

When I enable `tooltip.shared = true`, The arrow will disappear like screen shot.

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true
},
```

[image: tooltip without arrow]

I want to keep arrow just like `tooltip.shared = false`

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false
},
```

[image: tooltip with arrow]

DEMO in here http://jsfiddle.net/puff0211/5sbfztur/

Does anyone know to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you hover over the column `pears`?

Comment: @ewolden I expect the left sided arrow will display, and it will put to the rightmost edge of the bar chart.

but sometime it will put to center. (if screen don't have enough width)
keep left sided arrow will display, if cause this, that will be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)  with some css to achieve nearly required behavior but not exactly same when `shared: false`  .

[image: img]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      //type: 'column'
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -100,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 20,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
      borderColor: '#CCC',
      borderWidth: 1,
      shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true,
      backgroundColor: null,
      borderWidth: 0,
      formatter: function() {
        //console.log(this.points)
        var points = this.points;
        var pointsLength = points.length;
        var tooltipMarkup = pointsLength ? '<div class="callout right" >' + points[0].key + '<br/>' : '';
        var index;
        var y_value;

        for (index = 0; index < pointsLength; index += 1) {
          y_value = (points[index].y);

          tooltipMarkup += '<span style="color:' + points[index].series.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + points[index].series.name + ': <b>' + y_value + ' </b><br/>';
        }

        return tooltipMarkup + '</div>';

      },
      /*//you can use bellow code to adjust position
      positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {         
        return {x:point.plotX,y:point.plotY};         
    }*/

    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'John',
      data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
      name: 'Joe',
      data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
div.callout {
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85), rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85));
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #444;
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.right::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: 35%;
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/c8cdo7c1/1/embedded/#Result) demo

tooltip formatter

```
 tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  useHTML: true,
  backgroundColor: null,
  borderWidth: 0,
  formatter: function() {
    var points = this.points;
    var pointsLength = points.length;
    var tooltipMarkup = pointsLength ? '<div class="callout right" >' + points[0].key + '<br/>' : '';
    var index;
    var y_value;
    for (index = 0; index < pointsLength; index += 1) {
      y_value = (points[index].y);
      tooltipMarkup += '<span style="color:' + points[index].series.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + points[index].series.name + ': <b>' + y_value + ' </b><br/>';
    }
    return tooltipMarkup + '</div>';
  },
```

css

```
div.callout {
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85), rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85));
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #444;
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.right::before {
  left: -20px;
  top: 35%;
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.85);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent from skipping the tooltip anchor in case tooltip is shared by wrapping `move` function. More about wrapping can be here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts. Take a look at the example below.

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u6d2bode/